# How can I generate a document with text sections based on form responses?

Tags: forms

Based on a few questions, I want to generate a PDF report for my clients that provides different text sections that are inserted into a template based on the responses.

I have tried several things such as Form Publisher but they only allow to insert the form responses into a template. But they are not able to pull a specific text section based on a response and insert this into a template.

Any ideas? I am not a profound programmer but have gone through some basics. I am thankful for any hint into the right directions!

Comment: Please provide more details, such as the languages and systems you are using or considering, and where your problem/question lies exactly. You seem to be asking about research here, which you should be doing yourself first. See: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you using PHP, Python, Node, C#, something else? In general, your web framework will have a way of receiving form data, which you can then send into whatever library generates the PDF from the template. This sounds mostly like connecting different bits of library code together, but we will need more details first.